# Observe and update Room database within CoroutineWorker

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-workmanager

I would like to pass some parameters to a CoroutineWorker, make a query in my room database using this parameter and use the result of the query to run an url connection (obtaining an inputstream). Using the code I can read this problem in Build window: "Type mismatch: inferred type is CoroutineScope but ViewModelStoreOwner was expected".

**UserDao**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addUser(user: User)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateUser(user: User)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteUser(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE Name LIKE :name LIMIT 1")
    fun selectUser(name: String): LiveData<User?>?
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<User>> = userDao.readAllData()

    suspend fun addUser(user: User){
        userDao.addUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun updateUser(user:User){
        userDao.updateUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun deleteUser(user: User){
        userDao.deleteUser(user)
    }

    fun selectUser(name: String): LiveData<User?>? {
        return userDao.selectUser(name)
    }
}
```

**UserViewModel**

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: UserRepository

   fun addUser(user: User){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun updateUser(user: User){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        repository.updateUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun deleteUser(user: User){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun selectUser(name: String): LiveData<User?>? {
        return repository.selectUser(name)
    }
}
```

and this is the worker:

```
class DownloadingWorker(context: Context,params:WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

     private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        try {
            val Name = inputData.getString("Name")
            mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
            val LiveDataSelectedUser = mUserViewModel.selectUser(name = Name)

            LiveDataSelectedUser.observe(this, object : Observer<User?>(){
                fun downloadfunction(@Nullable user: User?) {
                    val UserUrl = user.url


            val url: URL? = try {
                URL(UserUrl)
            }catch (e: MalformedURLException){
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString())
                null
            }
            
            var list = mutableListOf<DownloadedData>()
            url?.getStream()?.apply {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
                    list = parseDOM(this@apply) as MutableList<DownloadedData>
                }}

            //// then I would like to update user with the downloaded data


                }}  )

 Result.success()
        } catch (error: Throwable) {
            Result.failure()
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Could .observeForever be a useful solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved passing from Livedata to Data with suspend fun in Coroutine.
In UserDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE Name LIKE :name LIMIT 1")
suspend fun selectUser(name: String): List<User>
```

In Repository:

```
suspend fun selectUser(name: String): List<User> {
    return userDao.selectUser(name = name)
}
```

In the worker I can retrieve data in this manner:

```
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        try {
            val Name = inputData.getString("Name")
            val database = getDatabase(applicationContext)
            val repository = UserRepository(database.userDao())

                    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            try {
                val user =  repository.selectUser(name)
                for(singleUser in user){
                val UserUrl = singleUser.url

val url: URL? = try {
                URL(UserUrl)
            }catch (e: MalformedURLException){
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString())
                null
            }
            
            var list = mutableListOf<DownloadedData>()
            url?.getStream()?.apply {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
                    list = parseDOM(this@apply) as MutableList<DownloadedData>
                }}}
                }

Result.success()

            }catch (e: Exception){
                Result.failure()
            }
        }
 return Result.success()
    }

}
```

Maybe it is not the perfect solution, but it works and hopefully it will be useful for someone else.